# Pygame, Python 2.7.3. Repeating obstacles

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Im creating a simple game with Pygame using python 2.7.3, where a ball has to avoid obstacles falling down towards the ball. But i cannot figure out how to make the obstacles fall repeatedly while also each obstacle falls randomly. This is my code:

```
import pygame
from math import pi
import random

pygame.init()

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE =  (  0,   0, 255)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
RED =   (255,   0,   0)
TAN = (252,231,182)
background = (38,37,37)

size = [400, 400]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

siz = 20
x = 200
xminus = x - 140
xadd = x + 140
y = 350
fallingy = 0
rectx = 0
rectl = 60
rectw = 30
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:

    clock.tick(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done=True 
    screen.fill(background)
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, [x,y],siz)

    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        screen.fill(background)
        x = 60
        circle2 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE,[x,y],siz)

    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        screen.fill(background)
        x = 340
        circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE,[x,y],siz)

    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        screen.fill(background)
        circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE,[xminus,y],siz)
        circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE,[xadd,y],siz)

    else:
        circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, [x,y],siz)
        x = 200
    """THIS IS THE CODE I WANT TO BE REPEATED RANDOMLY"""   
    def middle1():
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [rectx, fallingy, 170, rectw])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [rectx + 400, fallingy, -170, rectw])
    def lnr():
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [rectx, fallingy, 20, rectw])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [rectx +400, fallingy, -20, rectw])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [rectx + 100, fallingy, 200, rectw])
    def l():
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [rectx, fallingy, 20, rectw])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [rectx + 400, fallingy, -300, rectw])
    def r():
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [rectx + 400, fallingy, -20, rectw])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [rectx, fallingy, 300, rectw])
    """THIS IS THE CODE I WANT TO BE REPEATED RANDOMLY"""
    fallingy += 5
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the best way to handle bits of code that each need their own data attached is to write a class for it. You could roll your own class from scratch, but it may be easier to inherit from something like [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) which already does most of what you want (and can do a bunch more stuff too, like using a more complicated image instead of just a solid box of color).

Comment: Could you show me a simple example of how to use pygame.sprite.Sprite? Thank you for your response!

Comment: The documentation page I linked to has a link to [this search page](http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=pygame.sprite.Sprite) of open source code using `Sprite`, so you can see it in action in real code. Those search links are a new feature of the Pygame documentation, they used to have terrible example code submitted by users. They're quite nice!